# Can the word “deceiving” stand for “positive”?

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context, present-participles

I was puzzled with the line “(President Lyndon Johnson’s) appearances can be deceiving,” in the Washington Post’s (April 2) article titled “[President Lyndon Johnson did indeed attend an Easter Egg Roll](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/in-the-loop/post/president-lyndon-johnson-did-indeed-attend-an-easter-egg-roll/2013/04/02/2fdf5e20-9bb6-11e2-a941-a19bce7af755_blog.html?wpisrc=nl_pmpolitics)” with a photograph showing President Johnson at an Easter event at the White House on May 7, 1964.

My confusion arose from the contradiction of the phrase, “Appearances (which can be taken as 'attendance') can be deceiving” and the picture evidencing the obvious appearance of President at the site.

> “A March 29 Loop post said it appeared that President Lyndon B.
>   Johnson had not attended any of the White House Easter Egg Roll
>   gatherings. But **appearances can be deceiving**. Marilynn Eaton,
>   whose husband William Eaton covered the White House during the Johnson
>   years for UPI, sent us a signed March 30, 1964 photo of Johnson and
>   some kids, including her daughters Susan and Sally — seen sitting at
>   the far right of the stage.”

Why is it “deceiving,” not “positive” or “obvious” when appearnce / presence / attendance of Jonson were evidenced by a photograph?

Comment: *Appearances can be deceiving* is an idiom. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Appearances+can+be+deceiving

Comment: After several answers and comments, the basic premise of the question should not change. Else the history is invalidated. You may include a second-thoughts 'Edit' at the end of the question, though. As attempted to modify, it's an altogether different question that seeks a completely different answer.

Comment: @Kris. We have the similar Japanese saying- 人は見掛けによらぬもの-Hitowa mikakeni yoranumono -You cannot judge a person by his appearance. But it only applies to people.

Comment: "Don't judge a book by its cover." is the English idiom: it's also applied metaphorically to people, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP correctly gets the *appearance = attendance* allusion, but that's just a lead-in to the writer's main purpose - "wordplay" based on the (surprisingly recent, but now commonplace) saying...

[image]

(That's the [American corpus](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appearances%20can%20be%20deceiving,appearances%20can%20be%20deceptive&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) in Google Books. The [British preference](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appearances%20can%20be%20deceiving,appearances%20can%20be%20deceptive&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) is the other way around)...

[image]

It's important to note that the writer only uses *appearances* for the sake of the wordplay. The saying should be understood here as meaning *the March 29 Loop post gave misleading information* (what it said *appeared* to be true was manifestly contradicted by a photographic record). In this highly contrived context, the word *appearances* simultaneously refers to LBJ's *attendance* and *superficial/misleading presentation* in press releases concerning his activities.

---

I find it interesting to note that [appearances **are** deceiving/deceptive](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appearances%20are%20deceiving,appearances%20are%20deceptive&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) has been around a lot longer, as has [**may** be](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appearances%20may%20be%20deceiving,appearances%20may%20be%20deceptive&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). But in recent decades, [**can** be](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appearances%20can%20be%20deceptive,appearances%20may%20be%20deceptive&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) has become the standard version.

Answer (score 8):

The phrase “appearances can be deceiving” is idiomatic. It is a proverb meaning “things can look different from the way they really are”.[¹](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Appearances+can+be+deceiving)

Comment: The word, 'appearence' can be mistakingly construed as 'presence.' So did I.

Comment: The idiom “appearances can be deceiving” is used in both positive and negative senses. Or even when it's not possible to know either way.

Answer (score 2):

The word *appearances* there relates to the earlier instance of *appeared*.  The deceptive bit is casting doubt on the veracity or accuracy of the “apparent” claim.

Your text is saying that the supposition or assumption that LBJ had not attended was a deceptive one, in that he in fact did so based on the photo evidence presented.